# How can I get sqlite working on a shared hosting server?

Tags: python, linux, unix, sqlite

I'm trying to run a python script using python 2.6.4. The hosting company has 2.4 installed so I compiled my own 2.6.4 on a similar server and then moved the files over into ~/opt/python. that part seems to be working fine.

anyhow, when I run the script below, I am getting `ImportError: No module named _sqlite3` and I'm not sure what to do to fix this.

Most online threads mention that sqlite / sqlite3 is included in python 2.6 - so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

```
-jailshell-3.2$ ./pyDropboxValues.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyDropboxValues.py", line 21, in 
    import sqlite3
  File "/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in 
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

I think I have everything set up right as far as the directory structure.

```
-jailshell-3.2$ find `pwd` -type d

/home/myAccount/opt
/home/myAccount/opt/bin
/home/myAccount/opt/include
/home/myAccount/opt/include/python2.6
/home/myAccount/opt/lib
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/distutils
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/distutils/command
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/distutils/tests
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/compiler
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/test
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/test/decimaltestdata
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/config
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/json
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/json/tests
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/email
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/email/test
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/email/test/data
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/email/mime
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/lib2to3
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/lib2to3/pgen2
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/lib2to3/fixes
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/lib2to3/tests
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/xml
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/parsers
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/etree
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/dom
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/site-packages
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/logging
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/test
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/encodings
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/wsgiref
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/dummy
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/curses
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/bsddb
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/bsddb/test
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/idlelib
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/idlelib/Icons
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/tmp
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/lib-old
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/lib-tk
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/hotshot
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/ctypes
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/ctypes/test
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/ctypes/macholib
/home/myAccount/opt/share
/home/myAccount/opt/share/man
/home/myAccount/opt/share/man/man1
```

And finally the contents of the sqlite3 directory:

```
-jailshell-3.2$ find `pwd`

/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/__init__.pyo
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/dump.pyc
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/__init__.pyc
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.pyo
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.pyc
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/dump.pyo
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/__init__.py
/home/myAccount/opt/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/dump.py
```

I feel like I need to add something into the `sqlite3` directory - maybe sqlite3.so? But I don't know where to get that.

What am I doing wrong here? Please remember that I'm using a shared host so that means installing / compiling on another server and then copying the files over. Thanks! :)

**Update**
Just wanted to confirm that the answer from @samplebias did work out very well. I needed to have the dev package installed on the machine I was compiling from to get it to add in sqlite3.so and related files. Also found the link in the answer very helpful. Thanks @samplebias !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's build system [uses a setup.py file to compile all of the native extensions](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9f8771e09052/setup.py#l984), including sqlite3. It searches common operating system paths for the sqlite3 include and library dirs. If the sqlite3 development package is not installed Python will skip compiling the `_sqlite3.so` extension, but the pure Python portion of the `sqlite3` package will still be installed.

You would need to have the operating system's sqlite3 development package installed when you compile Python and at runtime: `sqlite3-devel` on Centos, both `libsqlite3-0` and `libsqlite3-dev` on Ubuntu.

Here's an example of the `_sqlite3.so` extension linkage on my Ubuntu system:

```
% ldd /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so | grep sqlite3
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f29ef3be000)
% dpkg -S /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
    libsqlite3-0: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
```

Comment: The machine I'm building on is ubuntu 64. Would I install sqlite3 (dev package) with `apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev` ? When building python, is there a syntax or will it be included automatically?

Comment: Yes, once you install the sqlite3 packages on the build host, Python's `setup.py` will locate them and compile the native extension. You'd then need to copy the relevant libs (including sqlite3 itself) to the hosted server and ensure the shared linker can locate them (you may have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for example). My other answer to a similar question [shows how to extract Ubuntu packages and use them without admin rights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976030/how-to-install-lxml-for-python-without-administative-rights-on-linux/5981037#5981037).

Answer (score 0):

In general, the first thing to do is to ask your host. I seems a bit odd that SQLite is not installed (or installed properly). So they'll likely fix it quite fast if you ask them.

Answer (score 0):

For python 2.4, you need sqlite and bindings, [pysqlite 2](http://oss.itsystementwicklung.de/trac/pysqlite/) or [aspw](http://code.google.com/p/apsw/)

Comment: Didn't the OP explicitly specify he's on Python 2.6.4?

Comment: @Eli, perhaps I misunderstood it. It seems that he has some problem with python 2.6 and since there is python 2.4 already on host, I guess a python 2.4 solution is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

None of the files listed in the `sqlite` folder is the `_sqlite3.pyd` Python shared library. Are you sure you compiled it when compiling Python? What does the build log say? I think there's a `configure` flag that needs to be passed.

Alternatively, just install [pysqlite](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite/)