# python module for html

Tags: python, html

I've seen few people ask this question. But what i'm looking for is more specific. I need a module that works with python 2.4 and it's only for html (not too new like html5) and potentially css. 
what i'm going to do is to extract info from a text file or from a database and write it to an html file. 
What do you think is best for this task? 
I'm new to python and i dont have time to play around with different modules so i need to get the "best" one XD 
I've looked up [markup.py](http://markup.sourceforge.net/) and [HTMLTags](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/366000-htmltags-generate-html-in-python/). what do you think?

thank you very much

*****I forgot! Could you also show me how to install the module without root access, if it requires one? T.T

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html)?

```
>>> from lxml.html import builder as E
>>> from lxml.html import usedoctest
>>> html = E.HTML(
...   E.HEAD(
...     E.LINK(rel="stylesheet", href="great.css", type="text/css"),
...     E.TITLE("Best Page Ever")
...   ),
...   E.BODY(
...     E.H1(E.CLASS("heading"), "Top News"),
...     E.P("World News only on this page", style="font-size: 200%"),
...     "Ah, and here's some more text, by the way.",
...     lxml.html.fromstring("<p>... and this is a parsed fragment ...</p>")
...   )
... )

>>> print lxml.html.tostring(html)
```

Outputs

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="great.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Best Page Ever</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="heading">Top News</h1>
    <p style="font-size: 200%">World News only on this page</p>
    Ah, and here's some more text, by the way.
    <p>... and this is a parsed fragment ...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh i've gone across that one but because of the name xml, it made me think it's probably not for me

Comment: btw, I just read the installation instruction. Looks like i need root access, which i don't. And it requires libxml2 and libxslt. I'm not sure if my work computer has the updated ones...

Comment: @BPm Yeah but you can get around that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976030/how-to-install-lxml-for-python-without-administative-rights-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

To use Python packages without installing them as root, unpack the [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) source code under your account somewhere and then run its `virtualenv.py` directly with Python to create a virtual directory.

```
$ python ~/virtualenv-1.6.4/virtualenv.py myvenv
$ cd myvenv
$ ls
bin/  include/  lib/
$ . bin/activate
(myvenv)$ pip install whatever...
```

And all the package installation you do while the virtualenv is active goes right into its `bin` and `lib` directories instead of the system ones, and the packages can only be seen by the `python` in the `myvenv/bin` directory.

I dislike creating HTML with code; I prefer using templates, so that a file that looks like HTML can pull in data provided by my Python script while still “looking like” HTML. Here is one popular option, but I lack `python2.4` on any of my machines to test and see if it will work on a Python that ancient. Good luck!

http://jinja.pocoo.org/