# How can I tell whether/where python a virtualenv has been set up? (aka installing lxml on bitnami's djangostack)

Tags: django, lxml

I'm working on a django application on the bitnami djangostack.  I want to use the lxml library, but I haven't been able to install it.  Or rather, I haven't been able to install it where django can find it.

I've already used apt-get to install the libxml2, libxslt, and python-dev dependencies. Both of these commands report success*:

```
sudo pip install lxml
sudo apt-get install python-lxml
```

easy_install fails with a super-long error message that makes me think it can't find the dependencies. (I've run into this problem before.)

When I open up python or call python manage.py shell and try "import lxml", I get

```
"ImportError: No module named lxml"
```

As best I can tell, bitnami has set up a virtual environment for django, and pip and aptitude are installing lxml perfectly -- to the wrong python. Assuming that's all correct, how do I get lxml installed to the **right** one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use apt-get install you are installing system libraries. BitNami DjangoStack is self-contained and independent. You could upgrade or remove your system libraries with apt-get and it would not be affected. Unfortunately lxml is not included in the stack nor libxslt which is a depency. We will include it in a future version however please find below the steps for manualing installing lxml on top of the python version included in BitNami DjangoStack.

You will need to use the system libraries for libxslt and libxml2. Be sure that you have them installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1.1 libxslt1-dev
```

Download lxml and uncompress it:

```
wget http://lxml.de/files/lxml-2.3.2.tgz
tar zxvf lxml-2.3.2.tgz
cd lxml-2.3.3
```

Load the BitNami environment:

`. path_to_your_djangostack_installation/scripts/setenv.sh` <-- notice the space between the dot and the path to the script.

`which python` <-- the output should be the python version from BitNami.

Install lxml specifying the path to your system libraries (notice that you should execute this command in the lxml directory):

```
python setup.py install --with-xslt-config=/usr/bin/xslt-config --with-xml2-config=/usr/bin/xml2-config
```

Now executing import lxml in the python console should work.

(This was already replied [here](http://answers.bitnami.org/questions/1765/use-lxml-with-djangostack))

Comment: Thanks -- actually, I posted to SO first, and didn't discover bitnami answers until afterward.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a couple of blog postings on installing this library on shared hosting. http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2009/installing-lxml-on-webfaction/ 
[How to install lxml for python without administative rights on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976030/how-to-install-lxml-for-python-without-administative-rights-on-linux)

Comment: Thanks, but my problem isn't really about shared hosting or write access: I have root access. The problem is getting lxml (and its dependencies) to install somewhere accessible by django.